# как сделать div справа в сетке bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

есть код:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12"> right side </div>
                </div>
           </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center"> </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center"> </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center"> </div>

          <div class="clearfix"> </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 text-center"> </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center"> </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center"> </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 text-center"> </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

как сделать чтобы текст right side мог быть на всю длинну контента, при этом следущие div после div class="clearfix" обтекали его ?

Comment: в каком смысле чтобы обтекали, если он во всю длину?

Comment: длинна правого дива (тот что с col-md-12) большая. может быть и 2 экрана, соответственно остальные 3 дива имеют такую же длину и весь остальной контент (тот что после clearfix ) уплывает вниз страницы. это суть проблемы. как этого избежать ...

Comment: разобрался, все оказалось просто. нужно сделать в .row две колонки .col-md-9 и .col-md-3. в колонку .col-md-9 нужно вложить еще один .row и в нем нужное количество колонок в соответствии с макетом.

Comment: @deni5n, если не трудно, оформите, пожалуйста, последний комментарий ответом.

Comment: @Nofate сделано.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментария автора:

Все оказалось просто. Нужно сделать в `.row` две колонки `.col-md-9` и `.col-md-3`. В колонку `.col-md-9` нужно вложить еще один `.row` и в нем нужное количество колонок в соответствии с макетом.